# Entry not generated in aspnet_UsersInRole Table ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I have create a create User Wizard in ASP.NET and added an additional dropdownlist Role for each user.

I have used the function ,

```
 
protected void CreateUserWizard1_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlRoles = CreateUserWizard1.CreateUserStep.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("ddlUserRoles") as DropDownList;
        Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, ddlRoles.SelectedItem.ToString());

    }
```

This creates a user and makes entry in aspnet_user, aspnet_membership table but do not create any entry in the table aspnet_UsersinRole table. I am joining these tables to get back required data but it is not giving desired result since for a user no entry exists in aspnet_UsersInRole.

Comment: Im afraid this question needs a little more to, i had this issue when using entity framework and not completing a correct mapping.
Are you using entity framework?

Comment: No @AshleyMedway , i am not using Entity Framework...

Comment: don't know why this is happening.... data is automaticaly entered into aspnet_Membership table but is not entered in aspnet_UsersInRole table...

Comment: Have you enabled roles in the web.config i will update my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check you have roles enabled in the web.config, correct with your right connectionStringName

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want DropDownList's selected value, you want to use [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx).

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(CreateUserWizard1.UserName, ddlRoles.SelectedValue);
```

***FYI:*** Please make sure you have created **Roles** in **aspnet_Roles** table in advanced. Otherwise, no record will be added in **aspnet_UsersInRole table** if the specific role is not found in **aspnet_Roles** table.